# GitHub - get users who commented or committed anything during a month

Tags: github, github-api

Is there a way to get it through GitHub API like:

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=is:pr%20state:open%20repo:angular/angular&per_page=100

I'm interested in anyone who contributed to the project in any way: PRs with code (including not merged/closed ones), who created issues, who comments in issues or PRs.

I'm not interested in guthub stars, likes, or emojis to the comments/PRs.

Comment: for code you can check history

Comment: yeah, I know :) but it is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `participants` for pull requests and issues using [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) like in the following example :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "mui-org", name: "material-ui") {
    issue(number: 23215) {
      participants(first: 100) {
        nodes {
          login
        }
      }
    }
    pullRequest(number: 23294) {
      participants(first: 100) {
        nodes {
          login
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You would be able to loop over all issues and pull requests in the following query :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "mui-org", name: "material-ui") {
    issues(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        number
        participants(first: 100) {
          nodes {
            login
          }
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
    pullRequests(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        number
        participants(first: 100) {
          nodes {
            login
          }
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try this in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository%28owner%3A%20%22mui-org%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22material-ui%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20issues%28first%3A%20100%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20number%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20participants%28first%3A%20100%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20login%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20pullRequests%28first%3A%20100%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20number%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20participants%28first%3A%20100%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20login%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

You would also need to get the `contributors` using [Github API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-repository-contributors) (which is not possible at the moment using GraphQL v4) :

https://api.github.com/repos/mui-org/material-ui/contributors

Comment: Oh. I thought it might be an easy way. But it seems like some GraphQL coding needs to be included. I'll try to find a simple solution. I accept this answer if I won't find it.